# How can I automatically update my javascript file to import newly detected files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, watchman

I tagged watchman as it MIGHT be the solution I'm looking for, but I don't quite know how to use it in this way!

I have a directory

```
/imgs
    /icons
        /bird.png
        /cat.png
        /dog.png
        /pig.png
```

and I have a file

```
/imgs/index.js
```

My index.js is responsible for importing all of the images and then exporting a single object for the rest of my project to use.

```
const bird = require('./icons/bird.png');
const cat = require('./icons/cat.png');
const dog = require('./icons/dog.png');
const pig = require('./icons/pig.png');

const Icons = { bird, cat, dog, pig };

export default Icons;
```

What I want to do is watch my imgs folder for new additions, and automatically update my index.js to import these new files and add them to my object. I need to import them with Common.js and export them with ES6.

Does anyone know a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential solution is to write a JavaScript script that generates your index.js like so:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const DIR = __dirname + '/imgs/icons';
const output = __dirname + '/imgs/index.js';

return fs.readdir(DIR, (err, files) => {
  let result = '';
  let references = [];
  files.forEach(item => {
    // assuming item has the format animal.png
    let newReference = item.split('.')[0];
    references.push(newReference);
    result += `const ${newReference} = require('./icons/${item}');\n`;
  });
  result += `\nconst Icons = { ${references} };\n\nexport default Icons;`;
  fs.writeFile(output, result, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(output + ' updated');
  });
});
```

Place that file (let's call it watcher.js for this purpose) in `imgs`'s parent directory and make watchman run it whenever changes in your icons directory are detected:

`watchman imgs/icons "node watcher.js"`

Notice that if a new file gets put into the watched directory, the index.js-creating script will not re-run. Only if it gets altered again (even if just gets saved again with the same data), the index.js will reflect that change.

You can simply test that by running `touch imgs/icons/crabigator.png` twice and look at the watchman log and/or content of index.js.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly was I was looking for!